# Apache shuts down unintentionally

Tags: centos, httpd, apache-2.4

> I must say that I am **not** the guy that set up the server, but the poor sap tasked with finding out what is happening for the time being. I only have a rough knowledge about apache and linux, so please bear with me...

### The Problem

An apache server of ours shuts down (mostly during the night) and fails to recover and start back up again, without anyone actually telling it to.

From what I can gather, the interesting thing here is the following line in the apache error logs:

```
[Wed Apr 15 03:43:02.114879 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25778] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

After which comes a *very* long stacktrace, here are the first few lines:

```
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/httpd': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f581d5c13c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d19d)[0x7f583b69519d]
/etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so(php_module_shutdown+0x2b)[0x7f58301d255b]
/etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so(php_module_shutdown_wrapper+0x9)[0x7f58301d2619]
[...]
```

The backtrace goes on for a while, but the interesting thing here is, that in between that, the `Error in /usr/sbin/httpd [...]` repeats itself 5 times, until the last message is

```
[Wed Apr 15 03:43:02.269626 2015] [core:notice] [pid 25778] AH00060: seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

The next message is on the next day me booting the server up again:

```
[Wed Apr 15 08:14:46.200884 2015] [core:notice] [pid 30326] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Apr 15 08:14:46.215410 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 30326] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Apr 15 08:14:46.235346 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 30326] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Apr 15 08:14:46.236045 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 30326] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Apr 15 08:14:46.280992 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30326] AH00098: pid file /run/httpd/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Apr 15 08:14:46.284919 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30326] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 15 08:14:46.284939 2015] [core:notice] [pid 30326] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

### Thoughts

As I see it, the [prefork-module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/prefork.html) somehow requests that the apache process (or one of them?) shuts down. This fails and in return the whole things just crashes horribly.

### Questions

First and foremost: Is my analysis - that the problem crashing the server is the *prefork* module -  correct?

Should I just disable the prefork module? I don't see how I can debug / help a memory error inside the software itself.

What implications does it have when I disable this module?

### Version information

```
Linux version 3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) )

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jan 12 2015 13:22:31
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:23
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

### Responses to comments

#### cron

There is no `/etc/cron.d/dailyjobs`, but only a `0hourly` script, which executes the hourly scripts `0anacron`, `0yum-hourly.cron` and `dellrda.cron` - None of which seem to do anything related to the apache (IMHO)

#### /etc/logrotate.d/httpd

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

#### Manual reload

```
/bin/systemctl reload httpd.service
```

Brings the following result

```
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

And in the `error_log` the same messages as above are shown.

A quick `systemctl status httpd.service` reveals:

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Fri 2015-04-17 12:26:36 CEST; 8s ago
  Process: 8828 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8826 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8767 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 8767 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
```

#### apachectl -M

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

Comment: The graceful restart in the middle of the night is probably caused by logrotate running at this time. When does logrotate run and what's in your apache's logrotate script? Please post the content of `/etc/cron.d/dailyjobs` and `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`

Comment: @etagenklo Done - I think the `/bin/systemctl reload httpd` is the culprit restarting apache, right?

Comment: What happens if you do the reload manually (i. e. issue the command `/bin/systemctl reload httpd.service` ?

Comment: @etagenklo The `error_log` shows the same messages as posted above, and the `systemctl` tells me that the *Job for httpd.service failed*.

Comment: Could you post the output of `apachectl -M` ?

Comment: @etagenklo Oh, well - thats a long one... But okay :D

Comment: You menton it's 'mostly at night', suggesting that it's happening at other times.  If it's not happening at a really consistent time (indicating a cron job), you might want to montitor memory usage and disk space on /tmp and / ... I've seen similar issues before when a CentOS system ran out of memory, and I can't remember if it restarted or just shut things down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess was that you hit this bug: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7669 , but I don't see mod_gnutls in your loaded modules. Nevertheless, to me it seems like you've hit some kind of bug. As I can see, you don't use the latest httpd version, so you should first try and update your httpd package:

```
yum update
```

Please restart your httpd afterwards, then try if the reload problem persists. If it's still there, I'd suggest to open a bug report at CentOS for this. To avoid the crash in the middle of the night in the meantime, I'd suggest to edit your logrotate script to use

```
/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
```

instead of it's `reload` counterpart until the issue is solved.

**EDIT:**

Before opening a bug report at CentOS, you should make sure that you are using only standard CentOS apache packages and modules. If you use any apache modules that are self compiled or installed from 3rd party repositories, they probably won't accept this.

To show all installed packages with the repo they come from, you can use the command

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME} %{VENDOR}\n'
```

Comment: Wow, what a research. I will look into these bugs and see if I can manage to update as soon as something happens there. In the meantime, thanks for the aweseome help. I can only upvote once unfortunately, you deserve a lot more :-)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, I've edited my answer with an additional thought...